# Why is QGIS holding references to layers that are not in layer list

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a QGIS project, which has about 30 layers in the layer list. I removed one of the layers from the list, saved the project, closed QGIS.
(The layer itself was from a Geopackage database, which has several other layers in it, which are still in the layer list).

I have reopened the project (few days later) and - the layer is still not in the Layers list (as you would expect).
However - navigating to the Vector Geoprocessing tools - The layer is listed there as a potential input for the Geoprocessing tool (if i select it as an input, the Geoprocessing tool simply fails after about 20 seconds).
I can add the layer back in, and it then appears twice in the layer list of the geoprocessing tools.

I can't see why this layer would appear as an input layer to the Geoprocessing tools, when it is clearly not in the Layers list.

Im hoping for some help in identifying why. More specifically:

- A Python query on either a standard Geoprocessing tool (like Buffer) and/or the layer list to see if it is listed there
- Console logging that I could implement on QGIS Project startup which would also help identify where it is being loaded as part of the project.
- Any other ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps, try the script in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364310/29431) to get rid of the name.

Comment: You could try to save as a new project. If the project was created under a previous version of QGIS, some now obsolete sections of the project won't be removed with a simple `save`, but only "up to date" sections will be carried over when using `save as`

Comment: Saving as a new project didn't solve this particular problem unfortunately.

Comment: You could try to save your project as qgs file (not the default zipped qgz file), than open it in a text editor and try to  edit the content to get rid of the layer manually.

Comment: @nr_aus - this sounds more like a bug than a question for this forum. If you can consistently replicate the issue, consider closing this question, and opening a bug report for QGIS. It's probably more appropriately investigated by QGIS developers.